# Change code to make use of multiple cores

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

For a project, I am trying to get the sentiment of different news articles. I am trying to do this using the `sentimentr` package. However, since I have quite some articles I am trying to speed this up by making use of multiple cores of my processor. The currenty code is as follows:

```
 library(sentimentr)
 #Extract sentences
 df_sentences <- text1 %>%
  select(content) %>%
  get_sentences()

#Get sentiment score
df_sentences2 <- text1 %>%
  select(content) %>%
  lapply(get_sentences())
```

Text1 is a dataframe which contains the articles and information about those articles, the `content` column is the column with the actual article text in it. I have looked online and found the `parallel` package which should allow you to do this. I have tried implementing this package using the code below, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make use of more cores since the speed stays the same.

```
library(sentimentr)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(sentimentr))
clusterExport(cl, "text1")
df_sentences2 <- text1 %>% select(content) %>% parLapply(cl, ., get_sentences)
df_sentiment <- df_sentences2 %>% 
  parSapply(cl, ., sentiment_by)
stopCluster(cl)
```

I hope someone can help me out and tell me if I am doing it correctly or what I would have to change for it to work correctly as it could save me a lot of time. All help is greatly appreciated! Sample data is included below:

```
structure(list(X = 0:4, id = 17284:17288, title = c("Example Title", 
"Example Title", "Example Title", "Example Title", "Example Title"
), publication = c("New York Times", "New York Times", "New York Times", 
"New York Times", "New York Times"), author = c("Example Writer", 
"Example Writer", "Example Writer", "Example Writer", "Example Writer"
), date = c("2016-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2013-12-31", 
"2012-12-31"), year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), month = c(12, 
12, 12, 12, 12), url = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), content = c("This is an example sentence. This is another example sentence", 
"This is an example sentence. This is another example sentence", 
"This is an example sentence. This is another example sentence", 
"This is an example sentence. This is another example sentence", 
"This is an example sentence. This is another example sentence"
)), .Names = c("X", "id", "title", "publication", "author", "date", 
"year", "month", "url", "content"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**Edit:**

I have changed the original code to incorporate the comment made by @F.Privé to the following, the time needed to perform the operation however stays the same. I hope someone knows what I need to change to get it working properly.

```
library(sentimentr)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(sentimentr))
clusterExport(cl, "text1")
df_sentences <- text1 %>% 
  pull(content) %>% 
  parLapply(cl, ., get_sentences)
df_sentiment <- df_sentences2 %>% 
  parLapply(cl, ., sentiment_by)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Content is the name of your variable ? Doing a select will keep the data.frame structure so that lapply will operate on only one element. If you want it to operate on the elements of that specific column, use pull instead.

Comment: @F.Privé that is correct, correct is the variable name which stores the text in the body of the article. So if I understand correctly I can use the current code but change the `select(content)` function and pipe text1 into `pull(content)` and that should work and use multiple cores?

Comment: @F.Privé I have changed the code (see edit), but the time needed to perform the operation stays the same. Do you have any idea what else I would need to change?

Comment: It's difficult to say without a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @F.Privé should I add some example data in the OP?

Comment: If you can, yes. Or some simulated data that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @F.Privé I have added some sample code in my OP, you should be able to simply copy and paste it into R.

Comment: And the function get_sentences?

Comment: @F.Privé Sorry if it wasn't clear, but that function and the `sentiment_by` function are from the `sentimentr` package.

Answer (score 0):

So, the best would be to split your vector in ncores parts so that each core is doing part of the whole computation.

In one of my packages, I have a function to do that with foreach:

```
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
library(bigstatsr)

res <- big_parallelize(text1[["content"]], p.FUN = function(x, ind) {
  sentimentr::get_sentences(x[ind])
}, p.combine = 'c', ind = rows_along(text1), ncores = nb_cores())

structure(res, class = c("get_sentences", "get_sentences_character", "list"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I don't have access to my pc right now, but if I use that code the output is the same and R is using multiple cores to complete the computations? Also, what would I have to change to change the number of cores it uses?

Comment: It splits `ind` in `ncores` parts. Then, each core of the `ncores` applies the `p.FUN` function to the corresponding part of `ind` (here, a block of rows). Finally, it combines the results with `p.combine`.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your help! I will test it out later and come back if I have any more questions, but I will most likely figure it out using your description.